# Ordenar objeto por sus indices en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

Cómo puedo ordenar un objeto por sus indices en JavaScript, con un objeto parecido al siguiente

```
{ave:2,gato:3,burro:7,caballo:3,hipopotamo:5,elefante:8}
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el objeto quede así ?

```
{ave:2,burro:7,caballo:3,elefante:8,gato:7,hipopotamo:5}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puede obtener las claves con el método [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), para luego ordenarlas con `sort()`, y finalmente construir un nuevo objeto.

```js
let objeto = {ave:2,gato:3,burro:7,caballo:3,hipopotamo:5,elefante:8};
//Obtenemos las claves y  la ordenamos
let claves = Object.keys(objeto).sort();
let newObject = {};
//construimos el nuevo array 
// asignamos como clave el elemento iterado
// y como valor el valor de dicha clave en el array principal
claves.forEach(el=>newObject[el] = objeto[el] )
console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Con sortBy de [Underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#sortBy)

```
var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 60}];
_.sortBy(stooges, 'name');
=> [{name: 'curly', age: 60}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'moe', age: 40}];
```

Comment: Esto realmente no me ayuda pues lo que necesito es ordenar un objeto por su clave no por alguna de sus propiedades